# Why does ssh look for keys in /root/.ssh when run with sudo?

Tags: ssh, sudo

When I try to `sudo ssh ...` I get permission denied because `ssh` looks in `/root/.ssh` for the keys, not in `/home/me/.ssh`. But `$HOME` is still set to `/home/me`. Why doesn't `ssh` look in `$HOME/.ssh`?

Comment: Why would you `sudo` the `ssh` at all?

Comment: I'm actually doing `sudo git` but it uses `ssh`.

Comment: There seems to be something odd in your workflow if you require the root user to own a Git repository... There may obviously be something involved that I don't know about, but a Git repository is unlikely to ever require to be owned by root.

Comment: "But `$HOME` is still set to `/home/me`" -- are you sure? By default `sudo` resets all environment variables, except a few like `TERM`, `USER` and `HOME`, which it sets according to the _new_ user.

Comment: It is an unusual thing to do, I agree. It's because I am running a benchmark as root (so I can use cpuset and reduce the runtime variance) and the benchmark script includes downloading and compiling a program. Theoretically I could make that bit run as non-root but it would significantly complicate things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ssh` ignores `$HOME`, it gets the home directory from the user database based on the *real*¹ uid (using the `pw_dir` field of the structure returned by `getpwuid()`).

Given that `ssh` could write files in there like the `known_hosts` one, it's just as well that it does not do is in `/home/me/.ssh` as you'd end up with a root-owned file there.

You can always use `sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ...`, or use an authentication agent and make sure you pass the path of the socket to that authentication agent to root:

```
sudo --preserve-env=SSH_AUTH_SOCK ssh ...
```

or

```
sudo SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ssh ...
```

Also, are you sure you need to run `ssh` as root? Is it to be able to create tunnels or bind local port-forwards on TCP ports below 1024? If it's just to be able to login as `root` on the remote host, doing `ssh root@host` should be enough.

---

¹ you could actually restore the real uid to our original one while preserving the effective uid of 0:

```
sudo perl -e '$<=getpwnam($ENV{SUDO_USER}); exec@ARGV' ssh ...
```

Answer (score 0):

While `sudo` allows you to "execute a command as another user" (`man sudo`), if missing, it will use "the default target user (usually root)". That's why it will look for the `root` account on the remote side.